# Expectation of log-Likelihood

Tags: likelihood

If Y1,Y2,...,Yn has distribution in exponential family depending on the parameters θ1,..., θp and       Let L(θ; y) and l(θ; y) denote the likelihood and log-likelihood,

then how can I prove [image: prove]
with the help of [image: hint]

Can I consider this [image] as a function of Y because if so then I can take integral of this times with pdf of Y1,Y2..Yn and then I can solve it from there.

But I am not sure if I can consider this as function of Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the score function has a null expectation at the true value of the parameter
$$\mathbb E_\theta^\mathbf Y \underbrace{\left[\dfrac{\partial \ell(\theta;\mathbf Y)}{\partial\theta}\right]}_{\substack{\text{random variable}\\ \text{as function of $Y$}}}=0$$
is unrelated with exponential families. Writing
$$\ell(\theta;\mathbf y)=\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(y_i;\theta)\tag{1}$$
and considering as a function of  $\theta$ the gradient of (1) (in $\theta$) is
\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial \ell(\theta;\mathbf y)}{\partial\theta} &=
\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial \log f(y_i;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{f(y_i;\theta)}\dfrac{\partial f(y_i;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\end{align}
by standard (calculus) derivation rules. Now, if one transforms the random variable $Y_i$ by the mapping
$$y \longmapsto \dfrac{1}{f(y;\theta)}\dfrac{\partial f(y;\theta)}{\partial\theta}$$
(which is indexed by $\theta$) one obtains another random variable
$$\dfrac{1}{f(Y_i;\theta)}\dfrac{\partial f(Y_i;\theta)}{\partial\theta}$$
Then the expectation of this (transformed) random variable under its distribution (indexed by the same $\theta$) is
\begin{align}\mathbb E_\theta^{Y_i}\left[\dfrac{1}{f(Y_i;\theta)}\dfrac{\partial f(Y_i;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right]&=\int \dfrac{1}{f(y_i;\theta)}\dfrac{\partial f(y_i;\theta)}{\partial\theta} f(y_i;\theta) \,\text dy_i\\
&=\int \dfrac{\partial f(y_i;\theta)}{\partial\theta} \,\text dy_i\tag{2}\\
&= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \int f(y_i;\theta) \,\text dy_i\tag{3}\\
&= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\,1\\
&= 0
\end{align}
assuming the likelihood $f(y_i;\theta)$ is sufficiently regular for (2) and (3) to be equal. (Which means it must be uniformly bounded by an integrable function, following [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement).) This proof is actually [available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics)).

Comment: ℓ(θ;y)=∑i=1nlogf(yi;θ)  (1) , here you assumed that Y1,Y2 ,...Yn are independent but what if they are not independent?

Comment: Then you have to decompose the likelihood according to the conditional densities.